# PHP not getting SQL date field 1970

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I'm building a site (my first!) which lists events,
nested when necessary inside year and month headers.
I know it's a bit of a mess, but hey!

I've made an error somewhere, and the date field from the MySQL DB isn't being passed correctly.
So it just defaults to 01-01-1970

```
<?php

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM events';
    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    $current_month = 'no_month_given';
    $current_year = 'no_year_given';
    $year_count = 0;
    $month_count = 0;
    $year = date("Y", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
    $month = date("M", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
    $startday = date("d", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
    $endday = date("d", strtotime($row['event_enddate']));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

    /* YEAR */

            if($current_year != $year) 
                {
                    $current_year = $year;
                    echo "  <div id=\"year\">
                    <p class=\"vert\">" .$current_year. "</p>";
                    $year_count++;
                }

    /* MONTH */

        if($current_month != $month) 
                {
                    $current_month = $month;
                    echo '<div id="month"><h1>' . $current_month . '</h1>';
                    $month_count++;
                }

    /* EVENT DETAILS */

}
```

Comment: your assigning `strtotime($row['event_startdate'])` before $row is set, turn on error reporting. also I see no `mysql_connect()` or `mysql_select_db()` so that could also be a secondary problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put these lines inside the while loop:

```
$year = date("Y", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
$month = date("M", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
$startday = date("d", strtotime($row['event_startdate']));
$endday = date("d", strtotime($row['event_enddate']));
```

because $row isn't defined before and you can't use the $row variable outside the loop because of it.